# Question on Strict Sense Stationarity - concluding about strict sense stationarity from WSS

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, random-variables

How do I ensure whether a WSS stationary process is Strictly Stationary or not?

The rules for checking for WSS stationary involve checking that the mean is not a function of time, and the autocorrelation is a function of the shift between the two instances of the random process.

But, from my understanding, for Strict Sense Stationarity, all higher ordered moments must be independent of t as well.

Now, manually computing all higher order moments is laborious, so is there any way to conclude about SSS from observation of the random process itself?

Comment: You cannot determine strict stationarity using moments. The only general method is to use the definition. In other words , you should know how to compute all finite dimensional distributions.

Comment: Can I find an example anywhere where they have used this general method?

Comment: Yes. An i.i.d. seqeunce $\{X_n\}$ is strictly stationary because the distribution of $\{X_k,X_{k+1},...,X_{k+n}\}$ is same as that of $\{X_1,X_{2},...,X_{1+n}\}$ for any $k$.

Comment: Thanks. In this note, can you tell me why the random process cos(t+Y) where Y is uniformly distributed in [0,1] is stationary? I found this as an example in many places, but can't comprehend the exact mathematical steps to conclude so.

Comment: $\{\cos (t+Y)\}$ is not stationary if $Y$ is uniform on $[0,1]$. It is stationary if $Y$ is uniform on $[0,2\pi]$.